# Getting coefplot to use estimate titles or outcome labels

Tags: stata, coefplot

Consider the following toy example using the *community-contributed* Stata command `coefplot`:

```
sysuse auto

reg weight i.foreign
eststo, title("Weight"): margins, eydx(foreign) post

reg price i.foreign
eststo, title("Price"): margins, eydx(foreign) post

coefplot est1 est2, horizontal
```

Is it possible to get the titles (or even the variable labels) in the legend, instead of the estimate names (i.e. `Weight` and `Price` instead of `est1` and `est2`)?

I know how to do it by hand, but I can't figure out how to do this automatically with many models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `estimates store` instead of `eststo` does the trick:

```
clear
sysuse auto

reg weight i.foreign
margins, eydx(foreign) post
estimates store weight

reg price i.foreign
margins, eydx(foreign) post
estimates store price

coefplot weight price, horizontal
```

Similarly, using a `list` and a `for` loop:

```
local list_of_names weight price

foreach item of local list_of_names {
    reg `item' i.foreign
    margins, eydx(foreign) post
    estimates store `item'      
}

coefplot `list_of_names', horizontal
```

You can of course use two different `lists` for variable names and 'labels'.

Comment: This works only when the model titles are single words with no punctuation, though this suffices for my purposes.

Comment: Yes, it is not perfect but you could go around that using camelCase. Underscores also seem to work.